# Establish a connection to another database only in a block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a rails application, I have this code in pure ruby :

```
class LinkCreator
  attr_accessor :animal

  def initialize(animal:)
    @animal = animal
  end

  def call
    "something#{link_id}"
  end

  private

  def link_id
    connection.execute(sql_request).first.first
  end

  def sql_request
    "SELECT field FROM table WHERE field_id = '#{field_id}' LIMIT 1"
  end

  def field_id
    animal.field_id
  end

  def connection
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      adapter:  "mysql",
      host:     ENV["MYSQL_HOST"],
      username: ENV["MYSQL_USERNAME"],
      password: ENV["MYSQL_PASSWORD"],
      database: ENV["MYSQL_DB_NAME"]
    ).connection
  end
end
```

As you can see, this is not a model but only a simple class. The problem is than the connection of activerecord is changed and the other requests, later, are executed on the new connection.

Is it possible to establish a connection only in a block and go back to the old connection. I know I can establish another connection but this is very bad for performance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It would be nice if you keep all database connections in `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  other stuff...
  
db_2:
  adapter: mysql2
  other stuff..

other_envs:
.....
```

Then create a class

```
class OtherDB < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:db_2)
end
```

From your controller you can access just like

```
OtherDB.table_name = "table_name"
OtherDB.first
```

Check my blog here http://imnithin.github.io/multiple-database.html

Comment: The important distinction here is that the connection is being made on an object other than the base class for all your normal objects - thus a connection to the normal objects can be left alone.   This also keeps configuration in a common place, and I think keeps the alternate database connection open which could be a good thing for performance, depending on your usage conditions.

Answer (score 18):

Have found most short example in Rails codebase at [activerecord/test/support/connection_helper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/801b33a4812c937a7e726d4060e2e3e9361c56fa/activerecord/test/support/connection_helper.rb#L2-L7) and slightly adapted:

```
def with_another_db(another_db_config)
  original_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(another_db_config)
  yield
ensure
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(original_connection)
end
```

Usage (given that you have `another_db:` section in your `database.yml`):

```
with_another_db(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations['another_db']) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT 'Look ma, I have changed DB!';")
end
```

Answer (score 10):

You can perform some queries within a block. First, define some module which will extend ActiveRecord, as below. This is a part of code used in production to change db connection per each request as well as to temporarily switch db to perform some queries within another database.

```
# RAILS_ROOT/lib/connection_switch.rb
module ConnectionSwitch
  def with_db(connection_spec_name)
    current_conf = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config

    begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_configurations[connection_spec_name]).tap do
        Rails.logger.debug "\e[1;35m [ActiveRecord::Base switched database] \e[0m #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database}"
      end if database_changed?(connection_spec_name)

      yield
    ensure
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(current_conf).tap do
        Rails.logger.debug "\e[1;35m [ActiveRecord::Base switched database] \e[0m #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database}"
      end if database_changed?(connection_spec_name, current_conf)
    end

  end

  private
  def database_changed?(connection_spec_name, current_conf = nil)
    current_conf = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config unless current_conf
    current_conf[:database] != db_configurations[connection_spec_name].try(:[], :database)
  end

  def db_configurations
    @db_config ||= begin
      file_name =  "#{Rails.root}/config/database.yml"
      if File.exists?(file_name) || File.symlink?(file_name)
        config ||= HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(file_name)).result))
      else
        config ||= HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
      end

      config
    end
  end
end
ActiveRecord.send :extend, ConnectionSwitch
```

Now you can use it as below:

```
ActiveRecord.with_db("db_connection_name") do
  # some queries to another db
end
```

Comment: nice piece of code. Did you considered to release it as a gem?

Comment: @sufleR, no I don't. Perhaps it's worth it.

Comment: @NoobieCorrect, this code is not thread safe.  Changing ActiveRecord::Base connection affects all threads.  You would need to create a new `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool` for the additional database, then you can wrap your code in a `my_conn_pool.with_connection` block.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to connect to postgres sql, you can use pg ruby gem & add the below code inside the block.

```
postgres = PG.connect :host => <host_name>, :port => <port>, :dbname => <database_name>, :user => <user>, :password => <password>
    tables = postgres.exec(query)

    tables.num_tuples.times do |i|
      print tables[i]
    end
```

To connect to mysql db inside a block, use mysql2 ruby gem & add the below code inside the block.

```
db = Mysql2::Client.new ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification::ConnectionUrlResolver.new(<database_url>).to_hash

    data = db.query(<<-SQL)
      select * from students
    SQL

    print data
```

Answer (score 2):

I use environment variables taken from Heroku's `DATABASE_URL` to connect to different databases:

```
class Database
  def self.development!
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:development)
  end

  def self.production!
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV['PRODUCTION_DATABASE'])
  end

  def self.staging!
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV['STAGING_DATABASE'])
  end
end
```

e.g.:

```
Database.production!; puts User.all.map(&:name)
Database.staging!; puts User.all.map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help to use an instance variable to store the connection.  Something like this:

```
def connection
  @connection ||= ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter:  "mysql",
    host:     ENV["MYSQL_HOST"],
    username: ENV["MYSQL_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["MYSQL_PASSWORD"],
    database: ENV["MYSQL_DB_NAME"]
  ).connection
end
```

That way the existing connection is retrieved on future connection attempts, rather than establishing a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try **active_record_slave** gem:

[Ruby gem: active_record_slave](https://rubygems.org/gems/active_record_slave)