# Rails connect to remote db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

How to properly connect to remote db?

Now i have

```
  def db_params
    {:adapter => "mysql2",
     :host => "host",
     :username => "name",
     :password => "pass",
     :database => "mydb"}
  end



 def connect_to_remote_db
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_params)
  end
```

When i write `connect_to_remote_db` it seems ok

I know that remote db has table `'Team'`

but when i write `Team`
 in console it returns me uninitialized constant Team

How to handle it properly?

Comment: is this your secondary database for the application?

Comment: @Nithin,yes i need to use one table from remote db.

Comment: is this code inside your `Team` model?

Comment: @nayiaw no. As i understand if i setup connection i can use my ActiverRecord models as always(i mean as i just start rails s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Team` ActiveRecord's primary connection is looked up, hence the error.

You could probably wrap that in class.

Since I had dealt with similar situation, you could have that connection in `database.yml`itself and use.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  other stuff...

db_2:
  adapter: mysql2
  other stuff..
```

Then create a class

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:db_2)
  self.table_name = "teams"
end
```

from - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26574386/2231236

Answer (score 1):

You need to create model in your application ( of that remote db table) and establish connection. Example:

**team.rb**

```
class Team< ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "remote_db"
end
```

If you have multiple table you want to use from that remote db, you can make module and just include it in every model for remote db table. 
Module example:

```
module RemoteConnection
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    establish_connection "remote_db"
  end
end
```

and than

```
class Team< ActiveRecord::Base
  include RemoteConnection
end
```

Use **database.yml** file to store connections:

```
...
remote_db:
  :adapter => "mysql2",
  :host => "host",
  :username => "name",
  :password => "pass",
  :database => "mydb"
...
```