# What are the consequences of establishing another ActiveRecord::Base connection? What happens to the old connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say my DB pool size is usually 2 but I want to increase it for certain tests that use threads to reproduce race conditions, using a method like this:

```
def with_db_pool_size(size)
  opts = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations.fetch("test")
  old_size = opts.fetch("pool")
  opts["pool"] = size
  #ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(opts)
  yield
ensure
  opts["pool"] = old_size
  #ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(opts)
end
```

Is this a reasonable way of doing it? Note the commented-out "disconnect" calls – if I run those calls, I ran into odd issues with dependency loading. Have not investigated deeply.

But anyway, my mental model is unclear here. If I connect with new opts like this, will there be an orphaned connection pool? Should I disconnect (and figure out why it caused those issues)? Is there a better way of doing it?

I've tried outputting `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.stat` here and there and things look like I expect – the pool size is 2 before I connect the first time, then whatever I set it to, then 2 again when I connect at the end. I'm just not sure if this leaves connections and/or connection pools behind.

Not a big deal for these testing purposes, but I'd love to understand Active Record connections and thread pools better in general.

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer my question, but solves the same problem.

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/43628899/6962 which covers this.

I changed the code to

```
def with_db_pool_size(size)
  original_config = ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
  #p original: ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.stat
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(original_config.merge(pool: size))
  #p after_est: ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.stat

  yield
ensure
  ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(original_config)
  #p after_ensure: ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.stat
end
```

This seems to do exactly what we want. `remove_connection` closes the old connection without causing the issues I saw from a straight `disconnect!`.

I left the `p` calls in above – those would show that the pool changes as expected.